# Elixir websocket/channel basic usage

Tags: phoenix-framework, elixir

I'm working on a PoC of a system where a mobile app client needs to be connected on a server with communications going both ways : either for updating the server or being updated by it. There is no client-to-client communications for the moment.

The client logs in the server via an HTTPS/POST method and gets back a token if the credentials are OK. This token is to be used by any further communication in order to authenticate the user. The reason why I'm using HTTPS for logging in is that there also is a web interface for other purposes.

I could not find a tutorial or documentation that explains how to implement this use case with channels based on websocket transport. All I found so far are either partial and focus on some specific aspects (eg authentication, setting SSL/TLS, etc) and assume the reader already knows the rest or are the over simplified implementations of the chat app. I'm sure I'm not looking at the right place...

My questions are:

1. What would be the list of callback to implement this use case on
   either side
2. On the server: how does a process send notifications to the
   client

NB: I'm using Elixir 1.5.1 and Phoenix 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Phoenix guide](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/channels.html#content):

> Each Channel will implement one or more clauses of each of these four callback functions — `join/3`, `terminate/2`, `handle_in/3`, and `handle_out/3`.

The page I linked contains also an MCVE of sockets running on Phoenix. In the bottom there are examples of how the [server-client communication](https://github.com/chrismccord/elixirconf_training/blob/master/web/channels/document_channel.ex) is done.

The only thing to apply this to your use-case would be to use one of authentication libraries (e.g. [`Überauth`](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth) that comes with great [examples](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth_example)) to handle token on each subsequent connection request.